# Connect PC to CAN bus using MCP2210 + MCP2515 + MCP2551

Tags: usb, can

I would like to connect my PC to a CAN bus to send and receive messages. Is it possible to use [MCP2210](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en556614) as an USB-to-SPI converter and connect it to [MCP2515](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010406) and then use [SocketCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN) to open a channel from the PC to the CAN bus? Will it work?

Answer (score 2):

Physically, there's no reason it won't work, but I don't think you're paying attention to either cost or software issues. First, you need a pc board to mount your chips (plus connectors). Second, and more importantly, your USB/SPI software will not deal with the SPI/CANBus conversion - you'll have to roll your own, and that may take rather more study than you realize.

Unless you're in this for the learning experience, I'd suggest you get a USB/CANBus converter with a software package that takes care of the interface. It will be more expensive than the chips alone, but may cost less when pc board costs are factored in, and will definitely save you grief on the software.